# HTML/CSS centering items in emails without the use of flexbox or grids

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm creating an email, so the extent of CSS that I can use is very limited to what Email clients support. For example, `display: flex` or `display: grid` aren't supported in many email clients.

I'm trying to achieve the image below, but I'm not 100% sure how I can achieve it without the use of grids or flexboxes.

[image]

Specifically, I'm not sure how to have just that `4.4` number centered (the number is generated dynamically, and it can have 3 or more digits in some cases), while keeping the arrow and the `0.2 above average` chunk of text offset to the right of the `4.4` element.

I also can't use the `:after` or `:before` pseudoelements, as those aren't supported in the majority of email clients either.

Below is a rough example of what I have currently. The issue is pretty immediately obvious just from the small snippet below.

```html
<div style="box-sizing: content-box; padding: 15px 0; width: 100%; text-align:center;">
  <h1>This Week's Ratings</h1>
  <h3>[IMAGE GOES HERE]</h3>
  <div style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h2 style="display: inline-block">100</h2>
    <p style="display: inline-block">↑</p>
    <p style="display: inline-block">20 above<br>average</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How would I go about modifying my above snippet to achieve the results I'm aiming for in the image?

Comment: The best practice to build _bulletproof_ email message is to use `<table>`. Table can center content pretty well and also have vertical align built-in. Email messages can be responsive even with tables. You can find a lot of examples on [Litmus blog](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-how-to-guide-to-responsive-email-design-infographic/).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `text-align:center` you can put all contents under a single div and then use following code to center the elements:

```
./# div_name{
    width:500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```